# Roozz player: How to get rid of?

Tags: uninstall, notifications, browser-plugin

I keep getting this popup every now and then on my Windows 7 laptop:

[image: Roozz Player popup]

I found this Roozz player in "Add/Remove programs" and uninstalled it, but the popup still appears. I do not remember installing this player. What is it, and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Currently (on May 27) there is no close button on the popup. Process Explorer says the popup is an HTML Application. On my machine, the command line is: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\mshta.exe" "C:\Program Files\Roozz\RoozzUpdated.hta" etc. So if you want to close this popup, just kill mshta.exe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am from the startup company Roozz. We are sorry that some people are unable to uninstall the Roozz player. We have located the bug and plan to make an update next week which will fix the uninstall problem.

We are also sorry that some people feel that our software is Malware. This is not the case or intent. The roozz technology makes it possible to run hundreds of software applications in the browser without installing them on the end users machine. We are also very careful about which applications we allow to run on our platform to avoid security risks to users machines. And we scan all applications for virus before they are released.

You can compare the Roozz player to Flash player and Silverlight. 
The reason we have decided to show information about the platform when the Roozz software are auto updated, is because many users have requested more up-to-date information about the platform. At least we do not install toolbars and additional software on users computers like many other freeware companies and download portals do.

Please contact the Roozz team for additional questions.

**Highlighting workaround in the comments until next release is out:**

> A temporary update is being rolled out that will ensure the notice is showed max once a week. Workaround before the next update is out: install the latest plugin version at www.roozz.com and then uninstall it, and for Windows Vista / 7 open Task Scheduler on Windows and remove the 'Roozz' task (one part of the bug is it fails to remove this).

Comment: This is great and I always welcome the innovation, but now how do I stop that popup from appearing every day?
Also I am curios, the popup mentions software like FileZilla FTP etc. are you saying that things like FTP client also run in the browser without installation?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter a Roozz developer here. A temporary update is being rolled out that will ensure the notice is showed max once a week. Workaround before the update next week: install the latest plugin version at www.roozz.com and then uninstall it, and for Windows Vista / 7 open Task Scheduler on Windows and remove the 'Roozz' task (one part of the bug is it fails to remove this). Re FileZilla, check it out: http://rent.roozz.com/FileZilla (that's a free one).

Comment: @eglasius thank you. I did not realize Windows scheduled task was creates as well. I removed and also ran `uninstall.bat` from the Roozz folder, now everything is gone. Funny that it looks like a very well done and useful service, only if it didn't look so intrusive and sneaky (I don't remember installing it at all) I would be willing to give it a try

Comment: Software that doesn't uninstall itself properly, nags users, puts unrequested stuff into the task scheduler etc etc is definitely in the "not good-ware" category - whether that be by design or accident. Consider me not only a non-user but also a vocal detractor of your application. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/)?

The free trial should be able to help you get rid of unwanted Malware such as Roozz player.

Comment: Malwarebytes comes in two forms: Free & Pro

Comment: Doesn't really help. Maybe because according second answer it is not malware? With popup it sure feels like one